# Installing Dropbox on ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I was trying to install dropbox on my ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. I have downloaded it but there is a problem while installing, it always shows,[image]

I have tried everything but nothing seems to work. I request to please help me out.

Comment: I've had no trouble installing on 20.04LTS and 22.04LTS. Can you explain how you tried to install and what you've already tried to sort it? I installed from the software centre and it works with no problems.

Answer (score 2):

Dropbox can't set the proxy. Use the [Headless Install](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx):

> 32-bit:

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" | tar xzf -
```

> 64-bit:

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
```

> Next, run the Dropbox daemon from the newly created .dropbox-dist folder.

```
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```